# What does it mean?

Tags: british-english

"Thou hast been smitten?"

https://www.google.nl/search?q=What+does+Thou+hast+been+smitten+mean%3F

Doesn't deliver real results.

Comment: Try looking in a dictionary—all the words in the sentence are easily found in any dictionary. Google is not a dictionary.

Comment: Welcome to ELU! You get an upvote from me for providing so much fun.

Comment: Literally, you've been hit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In contemporary English (though your tag is incorrect, it's not Old English, it's Early Modern English), we would write it as:

> You have been smitten.

*Thou* is a now rarely used, second person singular (and familiar) pronoun, for which we would normally use *you* today.

*Hast* is an even more rarely used second person singular form of *have*. It's the one word in this sentence that you might not find in some dictionaries (though you certainly would in some), and the reason I'm answering rather than just voting to close as general reference. (English used to end verbs with *-est* or *-st* in the second person singular).

*Smitten* is the participle of *smite*. It can mean the persona addressed was hit, stricken with illness, punished by a god, affected painfully by something, or has fallen in love (love being compared to illness in its irrationality and the ache that even requited love can bring).

Comment: It's interesting that both you and Baz say that the contemporary version would be *You have been smitten.* I would say that *to smite* is hopelessly archaic, and even though the past tense ***smitten*** still has some limited currency, the more common modern version by far would be *You have been **struck**.*

Comment: @Fumble, unless the meaning has to do with falling in love, that is. But then again, if it does, we wouldn't use the passive anyway—we'd say someone _is_ smitten (with/by someone), not that they _have been_ smitten.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's not completely dead. On wiki.answers I find "How do you tell a guy you met 8 years ago that you have been smitten with him since the day you met?", and Google gives me another 15 pages of "you have been smitten" hits, mostly blogs and ads (after the first page, which is mostly grammars).

Comment: @StoneyB and "smitten with a cold" and similar can also be found easily enough.

Comment: @StoneyB: Well, that's what I meant when I said ***smitten*** still has limited currency - basically it only survives today as a past tense in the ***love-struck*** sense. You won't hear anyone today saying *"If you smite me I'll be filing for divorce!"*, and even I had to think a second before offering *"The vicious bastard smote me!"*. For most purposes I think it's fair to say *the verb itself* is "dead" - there's just that orphaned past participle still lurking around in dark corners.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes - though the verb's still death-rattling among RPGers.

Comment: @Janus: Yes. I didn't consciously recognise the point until you made it, but at some level I was aware that (to the extent it was credible at all) OP's precise tense would be more likely to come from the knight's squire exclaiming *"Sire! Thou hast been smitten [a mortal blow]!"*. Although as you pinted out in another comment, even *he* would probably go for *"Thou **art** smitten, my lord!"*

Comment: @FumbleFingers I can't take credit for that - it was Janus Bahs Jacquet.

Comment: @StoneyB: RPGers often "reinvent" their own versions of archaic forms that never actually existed in the first place. But they probably like the word *smitten* precisely *because* it's archaic.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well, I played mostly with Shakespearean actors, not Lumpengamers, so we generally got it right :)

Comment: @StoneyB: I recall when I was about 13 our English teacher played us a few minutes from a recording of The Canterbury Tales read in what was thought (accurately, for all I know) to be the speech patterns of the time. I could just about understand the written text, but the spoken version might as well have been Japanese for all I could glean. I'm sure it wouldn't be *quite* so bad by Shakespeare's time, but I'm much more comfortable with the way they did it in *Shakespeare in Love* - just archaic enough to give the "feel", but not so much as to make it difficult or impossible to follow.

Comment: "Thou hast been helpful"? Thank you.

Comment: For what it's worth, I think the Old English would have been something like "ðu hæfst gebed gesmitted", with other spellings like "þu hafast gebed gesmitted", but I'm not at all familiar with Old English conjugations so I could be completely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This is an older form of English. In Modern English you would say: "You have been smitten". Here is the definition of the verb "smite": http://www.thefreedictionary.com/smite

Maybe the person has become sick or maybe the have fallen madly in love.

Comment: It is not old English, it is early Modern English

Comment: @Jon Hanna Correct! I've edited my answer.

Comment: I'd even say it's Modern English. Not a hundred per cent certain, but I have a nagging feeling that the perfect passive construction would be somewhat alien in EME. “You have been smitten” sounds like a more modern construction; I would almost assume the normal phrasing in EME would be simply _thou art smitten_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet For that particular context, I agree; but But in *The Memorable Works of a Son of Thunder and Consolation … Edward Burroughs / Who Dyed a Priſoner for the WORD of GOD, in … 1662* I find “the Cry of the Juſt, who hath been ſmitten and laid ſlain …”, dated to 1659, and GB has a couple more from the 1650s—so right on the EME:ModE boundary. Perhaps you're thinking of the progressive passives, which emerge in the works of the first generation of Romantics.

Comment: @StoneyB you can get closer to the form, and earlier, with "thou hast been" being in the KJV in 1611. Certainly "thou has been…" has been around for all of Modern English. The progressive passive is certainly later, but that would only rule out some possible interpretations of the participle *smitten*.

Comment: @JonHanna Fersher. But I concede that JBJ is correct in suggesting that the pre-moderns often used a present passive where we would use a resultative present perfect passive (and where the next epoch will probably use a GOT pr.pf.psv).

Comment: @StoneyB bring back the passival!

Comment: @JonHannr Pish. A vulgar upstart. Bring back the dative infinitive!